# toggle event handler doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a h2 tag so that when clicked, it grows and shrinks; I’ll use linear easing as it grows, and swing easing as it shrinks. The problem is that in my website, when the page loads the first paragraph automatically shrinks and dissapears.

```
$('h2').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({'height':'+=150px'}, 2000, 'linear');
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'height':'-=150px'}, 2000, 'swing');
});
```

You can check my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0v19nth2/14/) and my website [here](http://alvaroalonso.net/) (the h2 tag is "Greaty Agencie")

I would really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start out with the `h2` hidden.

```
h2{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Wowsk but the problem persists... it's occurring the same thing...

Comment: `$('h2').click(function() {
 $(this).toggle(function() {
 $(this).animate({'height':'+=150px'}, 2000, 'linear');
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'height':'-=150px'}, 2000, 'swing');
});
})`

Comment: Thanks again Wowsk! I did this before too and, although it doesn't trigger the event anymore when the page loads, the effect is the same:  h2 shrinks and dissapears instead of growing 150px (height becomes 0 and "display: none", it just doesn't make sense for me). In the fiddle it doesn't trigger directly.

Comment: In the fiddle you are not including jQuery, if you would do that it would be a lot better to debug.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I have updated the fiddle with the version of jQuery that I'm using: jQuery 1.11

Comment: I want to animate a h2 tag so that when clicked, it grows and shrinks 150px, not dissapear. Thanks for all your effort!